# Two super search forms on one page

Tags: supersearch

I have two Super Search forms on a particular url: /tours on our site, the first one works fine as the result page redirects to

```
tours/results/search&_category=700
```

but the second one shows everything there is in that particular channel, and the query string is missing. The url for the second form resolves into

```
/tour_guides/results
```

Why is it that the second form only works when {segment_1} is the same as the channel being searched from? Doesn't Super Search allow you to have one channels search form in one location, and the results page sitting on another channel?

Comment: You're probably going to need to post your template code.

Comment: Josef, do you have template code to post? Did this get resolved? If yes, please post your fix as an answer and mark your answer as the correct one by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.